# How to set outlined mat-form-field background color?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to change the background color of my searchbar. It has the `appearance="outline"` and I like the design, but if I set a new color it goes over the borders and looks ugly. What can I do here?

My CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 5%;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  top: -3px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  background-color: white;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<mat-form-field style="width:110%;" appearance="outline" >
    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
    <input type="search" name="test" [(ngModel)]="searchText"
    placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add `border-radius` to the div where you are changing the background.

I have tested `border-radius: 5px` and it looks good.

**Code for you**

I am assuming this background CSS is working for you. I just tried this with your selector.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Screenshot:** http://prntscr.com/nanu75

Comment: and How we can change for specific input field ??

Comment: you can append the `id` or `class` or `any special attribute` after this selector `::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline`

Answer (score 3):

This is hideous code but sets the background-color such that the its in the rounded portion only.  As opposed to seeing tiny corners of background outside the outline.

```css
:host ::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  background-color: white !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  background-color: white !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep mat-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: In Material 15 these are now `.mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing` and you need to add `z-index: 0`. Also I strongly recommend putting this in your global CSS instead of using ng-deep. Wrap it inside something like `mat-form-field.white-background` and apply that class to your form field. Now it works everywhere and is easy to change next time they break it!

Answer (score 0):

Angular 15+ classes changed. If you have rounded borders on an outlined form field, setting background color is kind of challenging.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="outline" class="white-backgrounded-field">
```

CSS: (preferably the global stylesheet)

```
.white-backgrounded-field .mdc-text-field--outlined .mdc-notched-outline {
  z-index: 0
}

.white-backgrounded-field .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.white-backgrounded-field .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.white-backgrounded-field .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just change your `background-color` to `color` and `!important` for override the **Material** CSS. Try this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: white !important;
}
```